# How to customise the highcharts plot in R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to use the `highcharts` `js library` in `R` to plot interactively -

```
library(highcharter)

Data = 
structure(list(date = structure(c(18361, 18362, 18363, 18364, 
18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 18373, 
18374, 18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380), class = "Date"), 
    variable = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
    "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
    "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"), value = c(-12.7015856459843, 
    4932.54512619195, 4337.84840857512, -1571.78718535286, -1475.28222178705, 
    4232.12003534889, 6536.12700338211, 2413.36143649343, 7711.43571028106, 
    5461.46337941179, 665.728647378994, 6007.98203770009, -900.505732433108, 
    12397.2655306638, 15182.2497643643, 4654.17811998194, 1673.36119858179, 
    10611.5994058113, 7510.88576801876, 20669.8626227112)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")


hchart(Data, "line", plotBorderWidth = 0.2, plotBorderColor = '#070707',
          hcaes(x = as.Date(as.Date(date)), y = value)) %>%
        hc_xAxis(title = NULL, reversed = FALSE, gridLineWidth = 1, type = 'datetime') %>%
        hc_yAxis(title = "", gridLineWidth = 0.2, minorGridLineWidth = 0, gridLineColor = '#070707', opposite = TRUE)
```

With this, I want to achieve below things -

1. I want total number of `grid-lines` will always be `10` in both `x` and `y` direction
2. I also want to have a `border` for the plot region

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gridLines are placed where the **ticks** are so if you want to have 10 gridLines, you need to have 10 ticks. You can set **axis.tickAmount** to 10, but this option works only with **'linear'** axes. Your yAxis is 'linear', but your xAxis is 'datetime'. You need to change it to 'linear'. When you do that, you will lose date labels formatting, so you need to format them on your own. To achieve that, I used **xAxis.labels.formatter** and **Highcharts.dateFormat()** method. To inject a JavaScript code, I also used **JS("...")** function.

To get a plot border, you can use **chart.plotBorderWidth** property.

If you want to define your tick placement on your own, you can use **axis.tickPositions**

This is the whole code:

```
library(highcharter)

Data = 
  structure(list(date = structure(c(18361, 18362, 18363, 18364, 
                                    18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 18373, 
                                    18374, 18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380), class = "Date"), 
                 variable = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
                              "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
                              "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"), value = c(-12.7015856459843, 
                                                                     4932.54512619195, 4337.84840857512, -1571.78718535286, -1475.28222178705, 
                                                                     4232.12003534889, 6536.12700338211, 2413.36143649343, 7711.43571028106, 
                                                                     5461.46337941179, 665.728647378994, 6007.98203770009, -900.505732433108, 
                                                                     12397.2655306638, 15182.2497643643, 4654.17811998194, 1673.36119858179, 
                                                                     10611.5994058113, 7510.88576801876, 20669.8626227112)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                           20L), class = "data.frame")


hchart(Data, "line", plotBorderWidth = 0.2, plotBorderColor = '#070707',
       hcaes(x = as.Date(as.Date(date)), y = value)) %>%
  hc_chart(plotBorderWidth = 2) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = NULL, reversed = FALSE, gridLineWidth = 1, type = 'linear', tickAmount = 10, labels = list(formatter = JS("function () {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d. %b', this.value);
            }"))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = "", gridLineWidth = 0.2, minorGridLineWidth = 0, gridLineColor = '#070707', opposite = TRUE, tickAmount = 10)
```

And here you can find API Reference for all used options:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickAmount
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBorderWidth